# Make a loop in a rails scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Here is my structure:

Villa model with a belong_to association with a destination model (destination_id).

User model with a habtm association with destination model.

Today in my index view, I use :

```
  <% current_user.destinations.each do |destination| %>
   <% @villas.each do |villa| %>
    <% if destination == villa.destination %>
      <%= villa.name %>
    <%end%>
   <%end%>
  <%end%>
```

It's not very clear, so can I make a kind of scope in my villa model to select Villas where destination_id == current_user.destinations ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you list the children villas from the destination itself?

```
<% current_user.destinations.each do |destination| %>
  <% destination.villas.each do |villa| %>
    <%= villa.name %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

If you want to forgo this built-in functionality, or if you're scoping a query further from your `@villas` relation, here's how you do the scope [as per these docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)

```
class Villa < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :by_destinations, -> (destinations) { where(destination: destinations) }

  # alternatively...
  def self.by_destinations(destinations)
    where(destination: destinations)
  end
end
```

Then refer to it with

```
<% @villas.by_destinations(current_user.destinations) do |villa| %>
  <%= villa.name %>
<%end%>
```